# Calculate a vector in meter from two GPS coordinates

Tags: math, gps

I need to calculate a distance vector from two GPS coordinates.
The purpose is to calculate the vector of one's change in position,
so the coordinates are not far from each other.
I would like to calculate the latitudinal and longitudinal distances in meters.

I found something [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/79633/how-to-determine-vector-between-two-lat-lon-points),
but this only gives the direction without distance.

Comment: Have you actually read the thing you have linked? It is something different entirely.

Comment: Yeah sorry, I didn't understand properly at first but now I do...
Also, I have found the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Due to the fact that those coordinates are very close in my case,
I made the approximation that the center of the earth and those two points form a triangle.
Thus, I can use the [Al Kashi theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_cosines).

Here is the code:

```
    // Common values
    double b        = EARTH_RADIUS + destination.altitude;
    double c        = EARTH_RADIUS + this.altitude;

    double b2       = b*b;
    double c2       = c*c;
    double bc2      = 2*b*c;

    // Longitudinal calculations
    double alpha    = destination.longitude - this.longitude;
    // Conversion to radian
    alpha = alpha * Math.PI / 180;
    // Small-angle approximation
    double cos      = 1 - alpha*alpha/2; //Math.cos(alpha);
    // Use the law of cosines / Al Kashi theorem
    double x        = Math.sqrt(b2 + c2 - bc2*cos);

    // Repeat for latitudinal calculations
    alpha      = destination.latitude - this.latitude;
    alpha      = alpha * Math.PI / 180;
    double cos = 1 - alpha*alpha/2; //Math.cos(alpha);
    double y   = Math.sqrt(b2 + c2 - bc2*cos);

    // Obtain vertical difference, too
    double z   = destination.altitude - this.altitude;

    return new Vector3D(x, y, z);
```

As you can see,
I have approximated the cosine because the angles are really small.
I think adding the altitude to the earth's radius doesn't give a better approximation,
but since I have it…

I tested it compared to Google Maps for a distance of 38 meters and I got a result of 37.877.
My result might be more accurate! ^^

Comment: Do you mean [the law of cosines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_cosines)? Wikipedia tells me it is referred to as “[Al Kashi](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Th%C3%A9or%C3%A8me_d%27Al-Kashi)” in french.

Comment: I don't get how “three points form a triangle” is supposed to be an approximation.

Comment: Yes it's the law of cosines, and I'm french :)
I misspoke, three points effectively form a triangle and it's not an approximation, the approximation is that the trajectory between the two points is not perfectly straight, so in that sense, modeling the problem here as a triangle is an approximation. A good approximation relatively to the distance between the two points.